# What is the name of symmetrical, orange/red flower?

Tags: identification, flowers

I saw this beautiful flower on flickr:

[image: beautiful flower]

Could someone please let me know the name of this flower?

Comment: The trouble with Flickr is there's often no info about the subject of the photo - this may or may not be real, but either way, the leaves aren't visible, which would give some indication of what this picture actually is.

Comment: I can not see the picture. @Bamboo can you upload it to the chat? Thank you!

Comment: @BYJ - I have no idea how to do that, but am mystified as to why you can't see it - J Musser might be able to do it for you, but if you can't see it here, I'm not sure you'll see it there either

Comment: Hey, I've seen at least two other photos of flowers that could have been photo-shopped on this site as well as other sites.  Hate to be so paranoid, makes trust tough.  If the OP can provide more information such as pics of buds, leaves and the entire plant, then I choose to trust and research.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is a partially opened [Lantana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lantana) flower. See comparison pics:

[image][image]

I think it is [*Lantana camara*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lantana_camara). See picture of *L camara* below:

[image]

Comment: Could you explain how you went from doubting that the photograph was real to being able to identify the plant? Search terms you used, etc. Thanks.

Comment: @NiallC. I viewed it first on my phone (tiny), and it struck me as computer generated or altered, being very symmetrical, square petaled and colored. But, walking back up the driveway later, I saw a lantana flowerhead and thought, "Five rays, in alternating disks evenly spaced, with decreasing sizes in each disk toward the center in the head, unopened individual flowers folded square, and coloring like *L camara*. Ovate opposite leaves with indented venation." Then when I viewed it on the desktop, I thought, "Why didn't I think of it before?"

Comment: I googled 'lantana flower buds' to get comparison pics.